# Howto add a virtual network interface to freebsd

Tags: freebsd, virtual-network

On Linux I would do:

```
 # ip tuntap add mode tun dev tun2
 # ip addr add dev tun2 10.125.0.1/24
 # ip link set dev tun2 up
```

How can I achieve the same on FreeBSD ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use ifconfig on FreeBSD. See below. The first command will give you the interface name that gets created which you can use for the next two commands. For the second command, you'll need to specify both the tun interface address and the destination address.

```
# ifconfig tun create
  output: tun0
# ifconfig tun0 inet 10.125.0.2 10.125.0.1 netmask 255.255.255.0
# ifconfig tun0 up
```